# bash script regex matching

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, grep

In my bash script, I have an array of filenames like

```
files=( "site_hello.xml" "site_test.xml" "site_live.xml" )
```

I need to extract the characters between the underscore and the .xml extension so that I can loop through them for use in a function.

If this were python, I might use something like

```
re.match("site_(.*)\.xml")
```

and then extract the first matched group.

Unfortunately this project needs to be in bash, so -- How can I do this kind of thing in a bash script? I'm not very good with grep or sed or awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xbraer@NO01601 ~
$ VAR=`echo "site_hello.xml" | sed -e 's/.*_\(.*\)\.xml/\1/g'`

xbraer@NO01601 ~
$ echo $VAR
hello

xbraer@NO01601 ~
$
```

Does this answer your question?

Just run the variables through sed in backticks (``)

I don't remember the array syntax in bash, but I guess you know that well enough yourself, if you're programming bash ;)

If it's unclear, dont hesitate to ask again. :)

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following should work

```
files2=(${files[@]#site_})   #Strip the leading site_ from each element
files3=(${files2[@]%.xml})    #Strip the trailing .xml
```

EDIT: After correcting those two typos, it does seem to work :)

Comment: BTW, these replacement options are all documented here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [cut](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cut) to split the string.

```
for i in site_hello.xml site_test.xml site_live.xml; do echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1 | cut -d'_' -f2; done
```

This can also be done in [awk](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?awk):

```
for i in site_hello.xml site_test.xml site_live.xml; do echo $i | awk -F'.' '{print $1}' | awk -F'_' '{print $2}'; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using arrays, you probably should not be using bash.

A more appropriate example wold be

```
ls site_*.xml | sed 's/^site_//' | sed 's/\.xml$//'
```

This produces output consisting of the parts you wanted. Backtick or redirect as needed.